# Printing a new column in a csv file with difference of two previous indexes from another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a csv file with 4 columns -> Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4

Assume the data in the csv file is currently:

```
Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4
10       20       30       40
12       23       78       98
23       67       101      123
```

Now I want to add 4 other columns which print the difference of columns, respectively:

```
Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4  Column5  Column6  Column7  Column8
10       20       30       40       2        3        48       58 
12       23       78       98       11       44       23       25
23       67       101      123
```

I am getting new data row every few seconds, so i want to make it so everytime new data gets added to column1 - column4, it adds the differences to column5 - column8.

Right now I am just adding rows one by one continuously

```
data = [b, c, d, e]
with open('dataset.csv', 'a', newline='') as myfile:
             wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
             wr.writerow(data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

#simulate importing csv file.
csvfile = StringIO("""Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4
10       20       30       40
12       23       78       98
23       67       101      123""")

df = pd.read_csv(csvfile, sep='\s\s+')
df

df_out = pd.concat([df, df.diff(1).shift(-1)], axis=1)
df_out.to_csv('Output.csv', index=False, sep='\t')

!more Output.csv
```

Output:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
10      20      30      40      2.0     3.0     48.0    58.0
12      23      78      98      11.0    44.0    23.0    25.0
23      67      101     123
```